# Want to get total of same string values in a column of gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

There is checkbox column in the gridview from which string value "P" is getting on checked. So, I want to calculate all rows of this column having same "P" values. I tried below code:

```
int sumP = 0;
public void countpresent()  //To count all Present Students in the gridview
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (dgvAttendance.Rows.Count-1); i++)
    {
        if (dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value.ToString() == "P")
        {
            sumP += 1;
        }
    }
    lblPresent.Text = sumP.ToString();
}
```

it is working for all the sting "P" but when it shows value null, it throws an exception "Object reference notset to an instance of an object". In the exception detail it is showing "NullReferenceException". 
Please any one suggest something to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws an exception because:

```
dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value
```

is null and you can't do a `.ToString()` on a null value.

You can check that it's not null first:

```
if (dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value != null &&
    dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value.ToString() == "P")
```

with C# 6 you can do this in a single line:

```
if (dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value?.ToString() == "P")
```

The `?` is short hand for the `!= null &&`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with full explanation. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check if the dgv row isn't null before you do your operation:

In C#6:

```
if (dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value?.ToString() == "P")
    {
        sumP += 1;
    }
```

Or in older version:

```
if (dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value != null && dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value?.ToString() == "P")
    {
        sumP += 1;
    }
```

Or actually, in older version, you could try use Convert.ToString, since it is designed to handle null

```
 if (Convert.ToString(dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value) == "P")
    {
        sumP += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Why should we use value.? here. Please explain

Comment: ?. Is to check if the Value is null. If it does, if won't execute the ToString afterwards. But if it is not null, then the ToString will get executed. It is kind of syntatical sugar in C#6 exactly made for case such as yours. Otherwise, we should write in as I show in "older version", which is longer. Remember that when your Value is null, you cannot perform ToString to it, because you cannot perform ToString to a null.

Comment: Glad to know that. You could also try to use Convert.ToString actually. See my updated answer. ;)